# Qt error: error: no matching function for call to ‘QHBoxLayout::addItem(QPushButton*&)’

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to add items to a QHBox, but I keep getting the error:

```
/media/root/5431214957EBF5D7/projects/c/qt/tools/plugandpaint/app/mainwindow.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘QHBoxLayout::addItem(QPushButton*&)’
     hlayout->addItem(m_button);
                              ^
```

What is it that I might be doing wrong?

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H


#include <QHBoxLayout>

class PaintArea;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

private slots:
    void handleButton();
    // Other slots

private:
    PaintArea *paintArea;
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout;

    // Other private items
};

#endif
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() :
    paintArea(new PaintArea),
    scrollArea(new QScrollArea)
{

    // Create the button, make "this" the parent
    m_button = new QPushButton("My Button", this);
    // set size and location of the button
    m_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100, 100), QSize(200, 50)));

    // Connect button signal to appropriate slot
    connect(m_button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (handleButton()));

    hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    hlayout -> addItem(m_button);
    hlayout -> addItem(paintArea);

    scrollArea->setWidget(hlayout);
```

Comment: Could you add more source code, please. I don't even see `m_button` declaration.

Comment: I just did @RealFresh

Comment: Which part of the error message are you struggling with? Did you read the documentation for the classes involved?

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev, you should use `addWidget` instead of `addItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [addWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#addWidget) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
hlayout->addWidget(m_button);
```

And by the way, that `this` beside the button name isn't necessary. The layout and the widgets above it in the hierarchy take care of ownership.